# Service Stack Request Filter Attribute custom Message

Tags: servicestack

I am using the RequestFilterAttribute to create a custom Filter attribute that check for Autentication etc. I am responding with 401 UnAuthorized Message for logins not authenticated and for Forbiddens I am sending a 403 Forbidden. How do I sent a custom message with the 401 & 403 messages , I want to send custom messages , do i use that statusdescription ? or is there another way for me to add the custom messages?

```
public override void Execute(IHttpRequest req, IHttpResponse res, object requestDto)
    {


            //Return unauthorized 
            res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            res.StatusDescription = "Not Authorized";
            res.EndRequest();


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the `IResponse.StatusDescription` is used to alter the Status Description on the HTTP Response.

You can still write to the Response if you want to send back more structured data in the HTTP Response body, e.g. this also serializes a custom `ErrorResponse` DTO:

```
var errorResponse = new ErrorResponse {
    ResposneStatus = new ResposneStatus {
        ErrorCode = "CustomErrorCode",
        Message = "Custom Message"
    }
};

res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
res.StatusDescription = "Not Authorized";
res.WriteToResponse(req, errorResponse);
```